# Need Help Matching Paypal API Return URL with regex in django

Tags: python, regex, django, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am looking for help making a regex url for this paypal api return url in django.

```
 https://www.example.com/confirm/?paymentId=PAY-3893HFBFBAF&token=ECAA320327QHGNAAFBLA2&PayerID=6R7EUHSHGAQY6
```

I need to capture the paymentID, token, and the payerID into my url regex function.

I have this which I know is really really wrong.

```
url(r'^confirm/?P<paymentId>[a-z][0-9]&?P<token>$[a-z][0-9]&?P<PayerID>[a-z][0-9]',views.complete_payment, name="complete_payment")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are `GET` parameters. You do not need to capture them in your URL regex. You can handle it in your view directly.

Example:

```
url(r'^confirm/$',views.complete_payment, name="complete_payment")
```

In the view:

```
def complete_payment(request):
    payment_id = request.GET.get("paymentId") 
    token = request.GET.get("token")
    payer_id = request.GET.get("PayerID")

    #... rest of the view
```